# Mongoose pre save method gives a type error in express typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb, express, mongoose

My stack is express js in typescript with mongoose. Here is my model:

```
import mongoose, { Schema, Document, Model } from 'mongoose';
import crypto from 'crypto';
import validator from 'validator';
import bcrypt from 'bcryptjs';
import roles from '../constant/role';

export interface IUser extends Document {
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  phone: string;
  email: string;
  password: string;
  role: string;
  dateOfBirth?: Date;
  emailVerified?: boolean;
  phoneVerified?: boolean;
  updatedBy?: Schema.Types.ObjectId;
  createdBy?: Schema.Types.ObjectId;
  passwordChangedAt?: Date;
  passwordResetToken?: string;
  passwordResetExpires?: Date;
  emailVerificationToken?: string;
  emailVerificationExpires?: Date;
  active?: boolean;
  fullName?: string;
}

export interface IUserMethods {
  correctPassword(
    candidatePassword: string,
    userPassword: string
  ): Promise<boolean>;
  changedPasswordAfter(jwtTimeStamp: number): boolean;
  createPasswordResetToken(): string;
  createEmailVerificationToken(): string;
}

type UserModel = Model<IUser, {}, IUserMethods>;

const UserSchema = new Schema<IUser, UserModel, IUserMethods>(
  {
    firstName: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, 'First Name is required'],
      trim: true,
    },
    lastName: { type: String, trim: true },
    phone: {
      type: String,
      trim: true,
      unique: true,
      required: [true, 'Phone is required'],
    },
    email: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, 'Email is required'],
      unique: true,
      validate: [validator.isEmail, 'Email is not valid'],
      trim: true,
    },
    password: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, 'Password is required'],
      select: false,
    },
    dateOfBirth: { type: Date },
    emailVerified: { type: Boolean, default: false },
    phoneVerified: { type: Boolean, default: false },
    role: {
      type: String,
      enum: [roles.SUPER_ADMIN, roles.ADMIN, roles.STUDENT, roles.GUEST],
      default: roles.GUEST,
    },
    updatedBy: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
    createdBy: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
    passwordChangedAt: { type: Date },
    passwordResetToken: String,
    passwordResetExpires: Date,
    emailVerificationToken: String,
    emailVerificationExpires: Date,
    active: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: true,
      select: false,
    },
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
    versionKey: false,
  }
);

UserSchema.pre(/^find/, async function (next) {
  const user = this;
  user.find({ active: { $ne: false } });
  next();
});


const User = mongoose.model<IUser, UserModel>('User', UserSchema);

export default User;
```

In vscode, I am getting this error in the line: `user.find({ active: { $ne: false } });`

```
Property 'find' does not exist on type '(Document<unknown, {}, FlatRecord<IUser>> & Omit<FlatRecord<IUser> & { _id: ObjectId; }, keyof IUserMethods> & IUserMethods) | Query<...>'.
  Property 'find' does not exist on type 'Document<unknown, {}, FlatRecord<IUser>> & Omit<FlatRecord<IUser> & { _id: ObjectId; }, keyof IUserMethods> & IUserMethods'.ts(2339)
```

Not able to figure out what is the issue here, and why does it say `Document<unknown`.

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

You have three choices:

**1. Passing the `Query<any, any>` as generic parameter for `schema.pre()`**

Let's check the TS overload signature of the `schema.pre()` method:

```
// this = Union of Document and Query, could be called with any of them
pre<T = THydratedDocumentType|Query<any, any>>(method: MongooseQueryOrDocumentMiddleware | MongooseQueryOrDocumentMiddleware[] | RegExp, fn: PreMiddlewareFunction<T>): this;
```

And the generic type `PreMiddlewareFunction<T>`:

```
type PreMiddlewareFunction<ThisType = any> = (this: ThisType, next: CallbackWithoutResultAndOptionalError) => void | Promise<void>;
```

So, instead of using type casting(`as`), we can pass the generic parameter to `schema.pre()` method. This generic parameter type will be the type of `this`.

E.g.(*"mongoose": "^7.3.2"*)

```
import { Document, Query, Schema } from 'mongoose';

interface IUser extends Document {
    firstName: string;
}

const UserSchema = new Schema<IUser>({
    firstName: String,
});

UserSchema.pre<Query<any, any>>(/^find/, async function (next) {
    const user = this;
    user.find({ active: { $ne: false } });
    next();
});
```

**2. Explicitly specify various `find*` methods**

```
UserSchema.pre(['find', 'findOne', 'findOneAndDelete', 'findOneAndUpdate'], async function (next) {
    const user = this;
    user.find({ active: { $ne: false } });
    next();
});
```

In this way, the type of `this` can be inferred as a `Query` type.

**3. Using [`instanceof`
narrowing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#instanceof-narrowing)**

When passing the regular expression to `schema.pre()`, TS will match below overload signature:

```
// this = Union of Document and Query, could be called with any of them
pre<T = THydratedDocumentType|Query<any, any>>(method: MongooseQueryOrDocumentMiddleware | MongooseQueryOrDocumentMiddleware[] | RegExp, fn: PreMiddlewareFunction<T>): this;
```

The type of `this` is a union type: `THydratedDocumentType|Query<any, any>`. And there is no `.find()` method on the `THydratedDocumentType` type, that's why you got the error.

We can narrow the type of `this` to `Query<any, any>` type using [`instanceof`
narrowing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#instanceof-narrowing) like this:

```
import { Document, Query, Schema } from 'mongoose';

UserSchema.pre(/^find/, async function (next) {
    if (this instanceof Query) {
        const user = this;
        user.find({ active: { $ne: false } });
    }
    next();
});
```